# Two contrasting definitions of "fiat"

Tags: adjectives

Would someone please explain and elucidate these two [meanings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fiat?q=fiat)? Why do they diverge and mismatch? A decree sounds much more prescriptive and resolute than an *arbitrary* order.

> 1. A formal authorization or proposition; a decree:
>      1.1. An arbitrary order.

I've heard of 'fiat currency' and apprehend this, but in the main, how would I determine from the context which of these diverging definitions applies?

Comment: It's arbitrary in the sense that it's "*because the king said so.*"

Comment: Alright, so you get the concept of *fiat currency* -- which of the two "competing" meanings do you think is at work in that concept? Hint: it's both.

Comment: It's an authoritative whim.

Comment: The two act independently and concurrectly. No contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

The definitions aren't really contradictory.  What *fiat* means is that something is established via an executive decision.  What gives it force is solely the authority of the governing body.  It doesn't have to be logical or natural or intuitive or fair.  Therefore a) it is usually established by a formal decree and b) it might be completely arbitrary --two aspects of the same phenomenon.

("Arbitrary" in this case means not founded in any larger principle *other* than the authority of the governing body.  The idea is that the governing body's authority is not, in itself, enough of a foundation to move something out of the "arbitrary" category.)

Comment: Thanks. Yet you wrote 'aren't really contradictory'? So is it somewhat contradictory? Your last sentence confuses me: how can a `a formal decree` and `completely arbitrary` be `two aspects of the same phenomenon`?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

A *decree* is not an *order*. For example, as King, I could *decree* that all Mondays are holidays. I could then *order* people to stay away from work on Mondays (definitions from Wiktionary courtesy of Wordnik).

[order](https://www.wordnik.com/words/order)

> n. An authoritative indication to be obeyed; a command or direction.

[decree](https://www.wordnik.com/words/decree)

> n An edict or law.

I admit I cherry picked those definitions for clarity. You will find definitions of *decree* that use the term *order* but the two are not necessarily identical. To further clarify:

> The King has decreed that blue must be worn on the third day of every month, I therefore order you to go home and change.